# geth 1.9.6 updated using homebrew on Mac Catalina gives cannot execute binary file

Tags: macos, homebrew

I recently updated to `Mac Catalina OS 10.15`. Today I updated homebrew and then upgraded ethereum (`geth`) to `v 1.9.6` using brew upgrade command.
After the update finished successfully, when I run `geth` I get "cannot execute binary file". (The older version of `geth` was working on `Catalina`)
It looks like the latest version of brew messes with the executable downloaded somehow.

I suspect this is a problem for any installs/upgrades done with new version of homebrew.

Does anyone have any solutions?

(Tip: for geth, I was able to download the executable from geth.ethereum.org/downloads and replace the binary - seems to work ok so far)

Comment: When you brew something in, it’s not necessarily notarized.